# gdal2tiles with specific bounding coordinate

Tags: python

I am using gdal2tiles to generate tiles from input BigTIFF but I want to use specific bounding coordinates for generating tiles.
is there any switch or option for this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Good questions require a thorough description of the situation, the desired outcome, and what you have tried so far.  Please use the [edit] button to improve your question.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the documentation https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html there is not any parameter for defining the target or source extents. Fortunately there is a simple workaround.

You can use gdal_translate and crop the input image with either `-srcwin` or `-prjwin` parameter. By using a GDAL VRT format https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html#raster-vrt the output is just a small XML text file so disk space is not wasted for copying the actual raster data.

As a final step use this cropped VRT file as an input for gdal2tiles.